# Understanding "當地的頭腦"

Tags: meaning, phrase

What does "當地的頭腦" mean? I saw a shirt with that written on it. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the earth and brain.

Does "当地的头脑" mean the same thing? Even if it doesn't make sense, would it matter if I bought it because it looks cool? I'm just worried it means something inappropriate.

Comment: "Head of a local place", that's the first impression coming to my mind.

Comment: Thank you! it makes sense now cause it is a local clothing business that supports the city they are from :D

Comment: Similar phrase: 当地的头头脑脑（们）, meaning the same thing, only it emphasizes more on plurality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`当地的` -> `local`
`头脑` -> `head`

`当地的头脑` means the head, i.e. the person having real power in local place. e.g.

> 而且当在国外在一些不发达的地区和当地的头脑打交道的时候，往往会需要因地制宜，使用一些非常手段，比如现金贿赂等等。
>
> 在洛阳北大街的万景楼饭店宴请祝绍周、警察局局长等洛阳当地的头脑吃饭。

Answer (score 0):

'Local big gun' 'A local with much influence' 'Someone who is full of xxxx'

Answer (score 0):

Word to word ,it means local head.
Like ali said 'A local with much influence' is a right way to understand it.

But I never see someone using this phrase and it sounds weird to me.
Maybe it only exist in some dialect.
I am a Chinese and i suggest you don't use it in the future or it will be improper.